# Rails where clause searching for foreign key fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to search a Rails table by using a where clause.

But, I don't have the right syntax for searching fields with a foreign key.

This is what I'm trying:

```
workorders = workorders.where("wonum like :search or description like :search or client.client_name like :search"
```

It works for `wonum` and `description`, but not `client.client_name`.

The workorder table has `client_id` in it.

Thanks for the help!

Update1

I'm getting this in the console:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "workorders" WHERE (wonum like '%Parks%' or description like '%Parks%' or client.client_name like '%Parks%' )
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "client"
LINE 1: ...m like '%Parks%' or description like '%Parks%' or client.cli...
```

Comment: Is your table `client` or `clients`?

Comment: clients !  But, clients.client_name won't work

Comment: workorders.include(:clients).where(...)- so that Rails knows to include the Clients table?

Comment: `NoMethodError - undefined method `include' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fde7e2f8f28>:` and `(gem) activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:45:in `method_missing'`

Comment: It's `includes`, not `include`. You could also use [`joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Comment: OK - got it - thanks!!  Enter an answer - I'll gladly accept.

Comment: I did have to us `clients.client_name` - seemed odd, till I thought about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`workorders.includes(:clients).where(...)` - so that Rails knows to include the Clients table.

Thanks @Reddirt for correcting my mistake

Comment: I think you also need to add: .references(:clients) at the end, in rails 4.2.10 doesn't work this without references